# Azure Worker Role - Receiving tcp connection to Port 25(Smtp)

Tags: email, tcp, smtp, azure-worker-roles, endpoint

I have an SMTPE implementation as an Azure Worker Role. I have defined two input endpoints (port 25 and port 2525). Listener at 2525 accepts tcp connections from smtp clients. However port 25 can't receive connections.

When running on emulator port 25 works fine. This issue occurs when I publish my worker roles to the cloud.

I use the same code for both. InputEndpoints are also defined the same way. The only difference is the port number.

Is there any limitation related to port 25?

Answer (score 0):

ISPs often block port 25, as do firewalls, as a means of spam prevention. Try telneting to a known address, such as 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 465'